# Hydrating Domain Model from multiple databases

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have an application with layered design as follows.

```
Project.Common      // Domain models
Project.DataAccess  // Repositories, Persistence models
Project.Services
Project.Web         // Presentation Layer
```

`Services` project uses `UnitOfWork` class (defined in `DataAccess` project) to query database. Repositories in `DataAccess` return domain models defined in `Common` project. 
`UnitOfWork` class takes connection enumeration to connect to different databases.

I come across an issue when I need to populate a domain model for which the data comes from different databases (different db servers). How would I do this?

It seems I would have to query separate repositories, with each repository returning a domain object (not persistence object since it is exposed to Services layer). And then build a more complex domain object from simpler domain objects in Services layer. Is this correct approach?

Sample code in `Services` layer to query database.

```
using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(DatabaseConnection.MyDbServer1, requireTransaction: false))
{
    var repo = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository<IMyRepository>(unitOfWork);
    IEnumerable<MyDomainObject> output = repo.GetData();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your business logic requires information from multiple persistence models (databases), then it would make perfect sense to define a new service model (in `Project.Services`) that will wrap this information in a single object. Then you would have a corresponding method in your service layer that will return this model by querying the underlying repositories.

Comment: My repos retrieve persistence models (which are internal to `Project.DataAccess`) and return domain models (in `Project.Common`). So should I use these domain models to define a new service model in `Project.Services` like you mentioned, or maybe create a more complex domain model in `Project.Common`?

Comment: You could use those domain models to build a more complex service model.